# Want to deploy my app to my domain, what to do when after eb deploy is successful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

Pardon me if my question sounds stupid, but I've been cracking my brain on this for quite a while, obviously its my first time deploying and i'm a beginner.

I've followed this tutorial (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html) to deploy my rails app to elastic beanstalk. Everything is successful, `eb deploy` is successful, `eb open` opens my application in the terminal(w3m) too.

BUT what am I suppose to do next? I mean

1. Am i suppose to do anything with the 'upload and deploy' button on Elastic Beanstalk Console? Currently its at Sample Application.

I've tried `aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name my-application --version-label v2 --source-bundle S3Bucket=(bucket name),S3Key=(zip file)`

but in return I get  `A client error (InvalidParameterCombination) occurred when calling the CreateApplicationVersion operation: Unable to download from S3 location (Bucket: name of bucket  Key: name of zip file). Reason: Moved Permanently`

2. What am I suppose to do at the hosted zones at Route 53? I put type: CNAME and value as the url in elastic beanstalk console, and obviously going to my domain says 'Congratulations Your first AWS Elastic Beanstalk Ruby Application is now running on your own dedicated environment in the AWS Cloud' since 'upload and deploy' is at sample application.

OR is my thought process all wrong? Hope someone can enlighten me and tell me what to do.  I just need to deploy my web app to my own domain. Thanks in advance.

I don't know if this is useful, the message after `eb deploy`:

```
Creating application version archive "(name of app)".
Uploading (name of app).zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
INFO: Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Info. Command is executing on all instances.
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
INFO: Environment update completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I feel dumb.

I just have to type `eb status --verbose` into the terminal, copy and paste the CNAME given into Route 53 hosted zone.